# find_all() function of BeautifulSoup doesn't return anything in cron server, but it does when run locally

Tags: python, cron, beautifulsoup

I am struggling to find out why the `find_all` function of beautifulsoup doesn't work in cronjob- but my code works perfectly when run manually in my local machine. The `print elements` statement shows nothing which shouldn't be the case. This might be something important. I am using `python2.7` and I hope I have used all the functions of `beautifulsoup` with `python2.7`

My code: (following the conversation with Alvaro below)

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime
import time
import mysql.connector
import os

os.chdir("/home/analytics/cronjobs/direc")
search = "some search term"
goog_search = "https://www.google.se/search?source=hp&ei=3_l6WsHAKMiasgHf26zYBQ&q=" + search

r = requests.get(goog_search)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
elements = soup.find_all('cite', {'class': '_WGk'})
print elements 

con=mysql.connector.connect(user='username', password='password!',
                              host='IP',
                              database='dbName')
cur=con.cursor()
pos=0
for tag in elements:
    res = re.search("(?P<url>www.[^\s,<]+)", str(tag))
    if res != None:
        z = res.group("url")
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        pos=pos+1
        insertstatement = ("INSERT INTO tableName(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s', '%s')" % (st,search,z, pos))
        cur.execute(insertstatement)

con.commit()        
con.close()
```

Is there any different way of writing the `beautifulsoup` functions in cron? What am I missing here? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you figure out your code works correctly on your cronjob? Just the fact that your print doesnt output doesnt mean your code runs. The cronjob machine might be erroring out on the `import bs4` statement and you'd never know.

Comment: @BoboDarph - Hi, thanks for your reply. I get huge chunk of text when I try to print the `soup` variable in cron, but just in the next line when I am using `soup` in `find_all` it returns nothing.

Comment: Sneaky suspicion it's because of different versions of BS4. find_all by class name is done like this in latest bs4 `soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")`. Notice the `class_` param. Sauce: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: @BoboDarph- No that didn't work out :(

Comment: @BoboDarph- Is it something to do with python2.7 version in cron? I have installed `bs4` like this `sudo apt-get install python-bs4`

Comment: So your next job is to print out all the version strings. `sys.version_info`, `requests.__version__`, and `import bs4; bs4.__version__`, then compare what the differences are. Also, check for proxy information. Print out `os.environ()` (`from pprint import pprint; import os; pprint(os.environ)`) and see what else could be different; especially if there are differences in proxy configuration.

Comment: Also the diagnose function might help: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#diagnose. If you have versions mismatch, I'd suggest running your cron job in a python virtual environment where you always install the proper version of bs4 for your script.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Just checked my `soup` output from cron server and soup output when I run the code from my machine. Both are different and doesn't show all the urls that I am fetching when I run it locally. I think this is because my cron server is in different IP. Any alternative to this problem?

Comment: @shomedrums: not really. Google is free to produce different responses to different clients as they see fit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters-  Yes , thanks for your reply! :)